# How do I get Android Studio's debugger to show disassembly in native code?

Tags: android, debugging, java-native-interface, native, disassembly

I'm developing an Android app that uses Java and C/C++ JNI.  I'm testing it on a 64-bit ARM machine.  Everything's working and I can debug everything properly when single-stepping in and out of Java or C/C++ source code.  I can examine memory and do regular debugging.  However, in disassembly mode nothing displays.  Just a blank screen with a current statement indicator, but no text, and the running app effectively locks up at that point.  I can't Step Out, Single Step, Continue, or anything else.  I have to stop the app and restart.

I don't know if I'm missing a plugin, or there's a setting that's wrong, or if that part of the debugger just isn't coded yet, or what.

Should disassembly show up in the Disassembly window?